# CSS disable <a> hover

Tags: html, css

```
<a>Link</a>
```

Can we prevent this element from having any hover effect without usin `:hover`?

I usually go:

```
a {
color= white;
}

a:hover {
color= white;
}
```

I've checked `pointer-event= none;` but it disabled the entire element and made it text.

Comment: You should not be using `=` in CSS, that will never work; and why is using CSS `:hover` a problem?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `:hover`?

Comment: You don't use `=` in css as it's not css thing, you can use unique color for link without stating the hover state in this way : `a { color:white !important; }`

Comment: please give your code or link where you are trying it, so that one can check directly there...

Comment: @Arsh: while you *can* use `!important`, you never should; it's rarely ever necessary if one uses CSS 'properly,' with care and attention.

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah i know about it. But as per OP he don't want to use :hover state. it's just suggestion in that case only. As if the anchor tag needs to be always same color (as stated in question) better also you can use `important`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your `CSS`, Please update your `CSS` with following code:

```
a, a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```css
 a {
    color: white !important;
 }

/*
  So you can actually see the white link 
*/
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

or if you don't want to use `:hover` you just add `!important` in your default CSS

```
a {
    color: white !important;
}
```

> Note: for standard practice we don't use `!important` frequently. So you can add this css inline. You can check updated code below..

```css
 

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" style="color: white;">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Don't use `=` inside CSS but use `:` instead.

To disable the hover (animation) do this:

```
a, a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: text;
}
```

However, if you assign a `href` attribute the link will still be clickable.
This you cant disable by `css` but you need `javascript` or `jquery` for that.

Example

```
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">test</a>
```

Comment: op asked how he can disable the hover state without using `:hover` and not how to disable the click event.